# How to auto press a button , when a activity is started

Tags: android

My main activity have 2 buttons,say A and B
I always press A, and go to 2nd activity

Please tell how i can do this automatically, like when i open my app, main activity is on, button A pressed programatically, and what user see is activity2 ,when opening the app

PLEASE DONT TELL ME TO REMOVE BUTTON B,or USE 2nd activity only
Beacause some background threads are needed to be runned on main activity,

Comment: then use performClick() method.like this buttonOne.performClick();

Comment: give Intent for 2nd activity in oncreate()

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: you don't want to press the button. Just run the code, which you run on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code at the end of oncreate() of mainactivity... this will surely help you

```
 A.performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonA.performClick();
```

Add this code to your main Activity